# apns and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, apple-push-notifications

I'm building and iPhone application the use push notification, all is ok. but now i'm going to build the server side with ASP.net. can any one help mee... coz i tired to get a solution using Google but unfortunately i didn't find any thing.

....

note: i tried this link http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-part-1/

but the post not completed yet

Comment: You've seen [part 2](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-%e2%80%93-part-2-generating-apns-certificates/) and [part 3](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-%e2%80%93-part-3-apns-certificates-registration-on-windows/) of that series? Part 4 is going to be about [the apns-sharp library](http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/) - are you using that? You might want to tag your question [apns-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apns-sharp) if you are. Have you tried the samples there?

Comment: no i dont want to use apns-sharp but unfortunately this is the only library that i found the use .net. ye i have read the part one and 2 and 3 (all this part didin't contain any .net development example)  do you have any idea,.... regards

Comment: OK; I'd encourage you to reconsider using apns-sharp because it's free to use (Apache 2 licence) and because it's already developed and tested. If not you might learn from reading the source I guess. Why don't you want to use it? No, I don't have any experience doing this myself sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw part 4 is out with a useful sample code. 
http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-and-c-%e2%80%93-part-4-apns-sharp-c-wrapper-class/

Answer (score 1):

After days of work. I chose to work with `Urbanairship` which provides a full push server:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/")
Dim postData As String = "{""aps"": {""badge"": ""+1"", ""alert"": ""Estez Mohamad lamaa!"",""sound"": ""default""}}"
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("uorecode", "uorkey")
request.Method = "POST"
Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
request.ContentType = "application/json"
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
dataStream.Close()
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
reader.Close()
dataStream.Close()
response.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [Prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com/) for notifications from ASP.NET:

```
public static void PushNotification(string header, string message)
{
    new Thread(() =>
        {
            var prowlURL = string.Format("https://api.prowlapp.com/publicapi/add?apikey={YOURKEY}&amp;application={0}&amp;description={1}", header, message);

            WebClient wc = null;
            try
            {
                wc = new WebClient();
                wc.UploadString(new Uri(prowlURL), "");
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (wc != null)
                {
                    wc.Dispose();
                    wc = null;
                }
            }
        }) { Name = "PushNotification", IsBackground = true }.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely finished.
I used it, and it works great.

However i'm not sure what's its licensing.